# MysqlDump Long Load Times

Tags: mysql, database, mysqldump

I am using `mysqldump database > output.sql` to dump all the data in a database. The size of the output file is around 3.3 GB. I am importing it using `mysql < output.sql` however it has been running for more than 24 hours and still hasn't finished.

Is this normal? Is there some way to speed up the import?

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%';
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                  |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
| have_innodb                             | YES                    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index              | ON                     |
| innodb_additional_mem_pool_size         | 1048576                |
| innodb_autoextend_increment             | 8                      |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608                |
| innodb_checksums                        | ON                     |
| innodb_commit_concurrency               | 0                      |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets              | 500                    |
| innodb_data_file_path                   | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                    |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite                      | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                    | 1                      |
| innodb_file_io_threads                  | 4                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                     |                        |
| innodb_force_recovery                   | 0                      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                | 50                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog          | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_log_file_size                    | 5242880                |
| innodb_log_files_in_group               | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir               | ./                     |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct              | 90                     |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                    | 0                      |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups              | 1                      |
| innodb_open_files                       | 300                    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout              | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                  | 20                     |
| innodb_table_locks                      | ON                     |
| innodb_thread_concurrency               | 8                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay               | 10000                  |
| innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm | ON                     |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+
37 rows in set (0.12 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%key_buffer%';
+-----------------+----------+
| Variable_name   | Value    |
+-----------------+----------+
| key_buffer_size | 16777216 |
+-----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%table%';
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| big_tables                 | OFF      |
| innodb_file_per_table      | OFF      |
| innodb_table_locks         | ON       |
| lower_case_table_names     | 0        |
| max_heap_table_size        | 16777216 |
| max_tmp_tables             | 32       |
| old_alter_table            | OFF      |
| sql_big_tables             | OFF      |
| table_definition_cache     | 256      |
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| table_open_cache           | 64       |
| table_type                 | MyISAM   |
| tmp_table_size             | 16777216 |
| updatable_views_with_limit | YES      |
+----------------------------+----------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Also, the tables are InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a disk space issue on my end. Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine that much data taking more than an hour or two on a reasonably modern machine. I'd use MySQL Administrator (found in [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)) or [mtop](http://mtop.sourceforge.net/) to make sure it's not just hanging.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your mysqld settings have been tuned to contain too low settings for memory usage.

For MyISAM tables, make sure you have key_buffer_size and table_cache properly tuned.

For InnoDB tables, make sure you have innodb_buffer_pool_size properly tuned. With InnoDB it also can be helpful to wrap the insert statements around a transaction.

Please post here output from the following commands:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%key_buffer%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%table%';
```

Comment: output added to post

Answer (score 0):

With
*show full processlist;*
you can see all process running, so if it's still inserting data, you should see it.

*SHOW OPEN TABLES

SHOW TABLE STATUS*
Should also give you some info. Give it a try and show us the results.

Should not take more than 2h. I agree.